# How stop QML Combobox Popup's items to be rendered outside

Tags: user-interface, combobox, qml, popup

I'm trying to create a Combobox in QML with custom items in it.
Each item must have two Labels/text.

I'm trying to customize it, changing the background etc. but the Items in the popup are rendering outside of its borders

How can I contain the items inside the popup?

This is the closest sample code I could get:

```
import QtQuick 2.13
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.13
import QtGraphicalEffects 1.15


ComboBox {

    ListModel {
        id: _dataModel
        ListElement { 
            name: "Account1"
            numbers: "12345"
        }
        ListElement { 
            name: "Account2"
            numbers: "12346"
        }
        ListElement { 
            name: "Account3"
            numbers: "12346"
        }
        ListElement { 
            name: "Account4"
            numbers: "12346"
        }
        ListElement { 
            name: "Account5"
            numbers: "12346"
        }
        ListElement { 
            name: "Account6"
            numbers: "12346"
        }
    }

    id:equipmentList
    anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
    width: 400
    height: 50
    model: _dataModel
    background: Rectangle {
        color: "#95A4A8"
        border.color: "white"
    }

    delegate: ItemDelegate {
        id:itemDlgt
        width: equipmentList.width
        height: 80
        contentItem: Column {
            id:rectDlgt
            width:parent.implicitWidth
            spacing: 2
            
            Text {
            
                id: _firstLabel
                Layout.preferredHeight: 20
                horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignLeft
                elide: Text.ElideRight
                color: "black"
                font.pixelSize: 16
                text: name
            }
            Text {
                Layout.preferredHeight: 16
                color: "grey"
                font.pixelSize: 14
                text: numbers
            }
            
        }
    }

    contentItem: Text {
        leftPadding: 20
        rightPadding: equipmentList.indicator.width + equipmentList.spacing
        text: "This doesnt work either"
        font: equipmentList.font
        color: "white"
        verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
        horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignLeft
        elide: Text.ElideRight
    }

    popup: Popup {
        id:comboPopup
        visible: true
        y: equipmentList.height - 50
        width: equipmentList.width
        height:contentItem.implicitHeigh
        padding: 1

        contentItem: ListView {
            id:listView
            implicitHeight: 150
            model: equipmentList.popup.visible ? equipmentList.delegateModel : null
            ScrollIndicator.vertical: ScrollIndicator {}
        }
        background: Rectangle {
            radius: 7
            border.width: 1
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You need to turn on clipping somewhere. Depending on what makes sense for your app, you could just set `clip: true` inside `comboPopup`.

Comment: Inside the ListView is the standard way: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtquickcontrols2-customize.html#customizing-combobox